# How do I get Yii2 prety urls and Apache

Tags: apache, url, yii2

I just installed Yii 2.045, but to my surprise, friendly Urls don't work. Although I have followed all the necessary procedure:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

I have also placed the .htaccess file inside the "frontend" folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|js|css|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
!^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

The fact is that when entering the address, Apache throws an error 500. When checking the error log, it indicates that it is repeating a pattern in the rewrite with de directive "add path info postfix", like this:

```
 [Tue Jun 14 00:02:58.022987 2022] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 6628:tid 1832] mod_rewrite.c(486): [client ::1:50575] ::1 - - [localhost/sid#1d74c1e9b28][rid#1d74eb5d0f0/initial/redir#7] [perdir C:/proyectos/mijail/] add path info postfix: C:/proyectos/mijail/frontend/web/frontend -> C:/proyectos/mijail/frontend/web/frontend/web/frontend/web/frontend/web/frontend/web/frontend/web/frontend/web/frontend/web/
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I think that `RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]` are making an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

You have an over-complicated, defective .htaccess file that is appending frontend/web in a loop.

If you are trying to just use [pretty URLs "out of the box"](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#using-pretty-urls), as you seem to imply, start with a simple RewriteEngine config in a .htaccess file **like the one below**, then you can tailor to your further needs (but in many cases, this config will be sufficient to run the show with Yii2).

Place it in the root of the /web dir for each app that you wish to use, e.g.

- backend/web/.htaccess
- frontend/web/.htaccess

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on

# if $showScriptName is false in UrlManager, do not allow accessing URLs with script name
RewriteRule ^index.php/ - [L,R=404]

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```